# Does any web browser allow writing to stdout?

Tags: browser, stdout, command-line-interface

I plan to write a [Hashify](http://bit.ly/dXYxGU) command line client, and I'd like to confirm that simply writing to `stdout` is not an option before getting creative.

(Ideally the command will behave like TextMate's `mate`, in this case opening hashify.me in a browser and waiting to be fed input.)

Answer (score 10):

[WGet](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (simple http fetching tool) supports redirecting a file to STDOUT with the `-qO -` option
called like `wget -qO - http://url/`.

[Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) (full CLI browser) supports dumping to STDOUT with the `-dump` or `-crawl` option.

Comment: [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) is another. It defaults to stdout; use `-o <file>` to output to a file.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at **Google Native Client**, available in the [dev](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2011/05/dev-channel-update.html) channel version of Google Chrome.

When run with the native client flags, it allows you to print to the terminal as stated [here](http://nativeclient.googlecode.com/svn-history/r395/trunk/src/native_client/documentation/debugging.html#printf). Look into the documentation [here](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/wiki/NativeClientInGoogleChrome) for details.

Getting it to work on *windows* could be a pain, but it (supposedly) works great on linux. I'm trying it out right now.